# mysql query duplicate urls associated with other indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table that lacks a unique key and want to find out how many duplicate urls are associated with other indexes. Is possible to query this?

```
| URL      | index         |
| -------- | --------------|
| /page1   | 1             |
| /page1   | 1             |
| /page1   | 2             |
| /page2   | 1             |
| /page2   | 1             |
| /page3   | 1             |
| /page3   | 2             |
| /page3   | 2             |
| /page3   | 3             |
```

I want to return

```
| URL      | count         |
| -------- | --------------|
| /page1   | 2             |
| /page3   | 3             |
```

to essentially find out which indexs have a duplicate url associated with another index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT` will in cobination with `HAVING` give your anted result

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`URL` varchar(8), `index` varchar(14))
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    (`URL`, `index`)
VALUES

    ('/page1', '1'),
    ('/page1', '1'),
    ('/page1', '2'),
    ('/page2', '1'),
    ('/page2', '1'),
    ('/page3', '1'),
    ('/page3', '2'),
    ('/page3', '2'),
    ('/page3', '3')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
 `URL`, COUNT(DISTINCT`index`) as count_
FROM table1
GROUP BY `URL`
HAVING count_ > 1
```

| URL | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| /page1 | 2 |
| /page3 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1bZKmqDE)